# General question: How to assign my SNP (Wheat, Illumina 15K) to specific chromosomes?

Tags: snp, chromosomes

I have 2000 lines of wheat genotyped with a 15K illumina chip. 
I also have the name of the SNPs. 
I would like to know how could I find out which SNPs are in each chromosomes.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from @devon-ryan, converted from comments:*

Look in Biomart to see if there's SNP rsids for wheat.